# .htaccess with trailing slash redirects to main page

Tags: regex, .htaccess

What I have is `http://site.com/index.php?i=1`
and want to work with:

- **[1]** `http://site.com/about` and
- **[2]** `http://site.com/about/` (notice slash at the end)

I use following rules:

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?i=$1 [QSA,L]
```

And this works only for **[1]** but if I put `/` at the end it redirects to `http://site.com`

I tried different options but or I get *not found* or *server error* or works only one of those. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have other rules in your .htaccess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want redirection for URI `/about/` to `/index.php?i=1` then your rule should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f   
RewriteRule ^about/?$ index.php?i=1 [QSA,L,NC]
```

Not sure why you are match everything by using `(.*)` there.

Comment: I want redirect both `/about/` and `/about` to `/index.php?i=1`

Comment: That's right and my code above will take care of both `/about/ and /about`

Comment: Still the same, without / works with redirect to the home page